# ebean - How to get the cluster status/health?

Tags: ebean

I'm configuring ebean clustering for cache invalidation (with ebean-k8scache to be specific) and I want to monitor and report the cluster's health. Digging through ebean's API I couldn't find a way to access clustering information.

Does ebean expose this information in any way? (metrics, functions etc.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **dumpMetricsOnShutdown**  see [monitoring](https://ebean.io/docs/monitoring/) ,The fast way to see what metrics are collected is to have them dumped when the server is shutdown , set below in configuration file:

```
dumpMetricsOnShutdown: true
dumpMetricsOptions: loc,sql,hash
```

- loc - include profile location
- hash - include the hash of the sql query
- sql - include the sql for queries

You can track the log see [logging](https://ebean.io/docs/logging/) , using the logger entries below :

```
<!-- L2 logging -->
<logger name="io.ebean.cache.QUERY" level="TRACE"/>
<logger name="io.ebean.cache.BEAN" level="TRACE"/>
<logger name="io.ebean.cache.COLL" level="TRACE"/>
<logger name="io.ebean.cache.NATKEY" level="TRACE"/>
```